# browser Allow/Disallow buttons on geolocation request

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Is it possible to attach event to browser geolocation request state?

When bar is visible show arrow to user... something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, You're going down a dark path of having to have a different help text for various versions of browsers/types/etc.

For instance, Firefox 29.0.1 permission window:

[image: FireFox 29 Geo Permissions]

In any event, I would suggest a variation of Nerdicus recommendation:

Instead of defaulting to show the arrow & then just hiding it when the JavaScript gets called, I would default display: none;, and then trigger a .show() right before you make the geolocation request to reduce your "flicker", and then hide it in your success/error callback.

Additionally, in your success handler, you can create a cookie (probably at the session level)

```
$.cookie("geoperm", "true")
```

Then you can check for existing permissions before showing the tooltip:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  // Show the arrow here, but only if there isn't a cookie stating we have permissions
  if(!$.cookie("geoperm")) $("#geo-helper").show();

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always detect whether the user allows / deny's geolocation, and from there, hide the large arrow pointing to the accept/deny prompt.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    error('not supported');
}
```

Comment: Once user clicks allow, and revisits site, there is considerable lag (2-3secs) before browser hides arrow. The result on first run it works perfectly, on consecutive runs arrow is displayed without browser bar.

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that `navigator.geolocation` returns `false` in case the browser itself doesn't support the geolocation API. It has noting to do with permissions the user might (or might not) give to the site to access his/her location.

For further information, I suggest reading [this html5doctor.com article](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/).